# I got some unexpected charracters when trying to pass object to client site

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I got this unexpected charracters when i'm trying to pass object from database to client site.My code:

```
exports.getAllProducts = async (req,res,next) => {

    const search = 
    new searchFeatures(Item.find(), req.query).
    filter().
    sort()

    const items = await search.search;

    const itemsStr = JSON.stringify(items)
    console.log(itemsStr)

    res.status(200).render('products', {
        title: 'Products',
        type: 'container__shop',
        items,
        itemsStr
    })
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0FrD.png

Comment: How did you get the characters you are talking about. Did you do ``console.log()``?
Is it item or itemsStr? Also, post text instead of an image. It is easy to read and copy.

Comment: What type of database are you reading from and what library are you using?

Comment: is there a reason you are not doing resp.json({}) ?

Comment: i found that the problem was with decoding in pug 
let itemStr = "!{itemsStr}"
But now i got Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when use JSON.strinfify, when i use toString() i got Object.object

Comment: when i'm decoding i got the error else i got these characters

Comment: I solved, the problem was that I used double brackets instead of single. They were in conflict with the brackets at JSON